# Custom Item BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, bottom-navigation-view, menuitem

Необходимо реализовать по нажатию на кнопку появление круга за пределами меню

*примерно так* 
[image: bottom menu]

как я могу это сделать?

Comment: библиотеки смотрели?

Comment: Смотрел bottom bar, помечен как deprecated

Comment: есть еще например bottomNavgationView

Comment: https://proandroiddev.com/how-i-drew-custom-shapes-in-bottom-bar-c4539d86afd7